# incorrect output data after the second index

Tags: c

So im doing this homework for my programming class, but the data output doesnt match with the theoretical data output that it shoud be printing and it gives me a big number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void menu(int *);
void CalculoVentas(float ventas[50][7], float ventasXproductos[50], int);
void PromedioDiario(float promedioXdia[7], float ventas[50][7], int);

int main()
{
    char ciclos;
    int sel, cont = 0, i = 0;
    float ventas[50][7], ventasXproductos[50], promedioXdia[7];
    bool lectura = false;

    while(sel != 5)
        {
            menu(&sel);

            system("cls");

            switch(sel)
            {
                case 1:
                    printf("Hay Productos?: S/N ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%c", &ciclos);
                    while(ciclos == 's' || ciclos == 'S' && cont < 50)
                        {
                            for(i=0;i<7;i++)
                                {
                                    do
                                    {
                                        printf("Teclea los ingresos generados por el producto %d el dia %d: ", cont+1, i+1);
                                        scanf("%f", &ventas[cont][i]);
                                    }while(ventas[cont][i] < 0);
                                    printf("\n\n");
                                }

                            cont++;

                            system("cls");

                            printf("Hay Productos?: S/N ");
                            fflush(stdin);
                            scanf("%c", &ciclos);
                            lectura = true;
                        }

                break;

                case 2:
                    if(lectura == false)
                        printf("Primero ingresa los datos del producto!!!\n");
                    else
                        CalculoVentas(ventas, ventasXproductos, cont);
                break;

                case 3:
                    if(lectura == false)
                        printf("Primero ingresa los datos del producto!!!\n");
                    else
                        PromedioDiario(promedioXdia, ventas, cont);
                break;

                case 4:
                    if(lectura == false)
                        printf("Primero ingresa los datos del producto!!!\n");
                    else
                        printf("%35s\n", "Total de ventas");

                        for(i=0;i<cont;i++)
                            printf("%d %.2f\n", i+1, ventasXproductos[i]);

                        printf("\n\n\n\n");

                        printf("%35s\n", "Promedio de ventas por dia");

                        for(i=0;i<7;i++)
                            printf("Dia %d: %.2f\n", i+1, promedioXdia[i]);

                        printf("\n\n\n\n");

                break;

            }

        }
}

void menu(int *seleccion)
{
    printf("%20s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", "Menu de opciones", "1.-lectura de datos", "2.-calculo de ventas por producto", "3.-promedio de ventas de cada dia", "4.-imprimir resultados", "5.-salir");
        do{
            printf("Seleccione una opcion: ");
            scanf("%d", &*seleccion);
        }while(*seleccion <= 0 || *seleccion > 5);
}

void CalculoVentas(float ventas[50][7], float ventasXproducto[50], int cont)
{
    //realizar el calculo de ventas por productos, nada más es la suma de las ventas de todos los dias por producto
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0 ; i<cont ; i++)
        for (j = 0 ; j < 7 ; j++)
            ventasXproducto[i] = ventasXproducto[i] + ventas[i][j];
}

void PromedioDiario(float promedioXdia[7], float ventas[50][7], int cont)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<cont; j++)
                promedioXdia[i] = promedioXdia[i] + ventas[j][i];
            promedioXdia[i] = promedioXdia[i]/cont;
        }
}
```

the output is something like this, I try to type simple data so i can know easly if its wrong

```
                    Total de ventas
1 70.00
2 5103881324019006800000000000000000.00
3 210.00
4 280.00




         Promedio de ventas por dia
Dia 1: 25.00
Dia 2: 25.00
Dia 3: 25.00
Dia 4: 1291386862541487300000000000000000.00
Dia 5: 25.00
Dia 6: -1.#R
Dia 7: 25.00
```

when i was trying to get help someone told me that i might be not initializing correctly the variables but i couldnt find any issue with that

Comment: What is the value of `int sel` when you test `while(sel != 5)` on the first iteration? (it's uninitialized) That invokes *Undefined Behavior* in your code -- All bets are off at that point. Fix that first.

Answer (score 1):

When the program begins, `sel` is *uninitialized* and contains a garbage value. This garbage value is used in the `while` condition on its first iteration

```
while(sel != 5)
```

and as such invokes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

You must restructure your loop to not read this uninitialized value, or simply initialize `sel` (to something other than `5`).

Similarly, the contents of `ventas`, `ventasXproductos`,  and `promedioXdia` are all uninitialized as well.

This means statements such as

```
ventasXproducto[i] = ventasXproducto[i] + ventas[i][j];
/* ... and ... */
promedioXdia[i] = promedioXdia[i]/cont;
```

will be operating with garbage values to start.

You can fix this by initializing your arrays:

```
float ventas[50][7] = { 0 }, ventasXproductos[50] = { 0 }, promedioXdia[7] = { 0 };
```

---

You should not ignore the return value of `scanf`. You should always check that its return value is the expected number of successful conversions, otherwise you will find yourself operating on incomplete data.

```
/* An example */
if (2 != scanf("%d%d", &num1, &num2)) {
    /* handle failure */
}
```

*(Better yet: avoid using `scanf`, and use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to read and parse lines of input.)*

---

You should clarify this expression by adding more parenthesis, otherwise you will run into issues with [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence):

```
while ((ciclos == 's' || ciclos == 'S') && cont < 50)
```

---

`case 4` of the `switch` has misleading indentation. Only the first statement with the call to `printf` is contained within the `else` block. It is read as:

```
if(lectura == false)
    printf("Primero ingresa los datos del producto!!!\n");
else
    printf("%35s\n", "Total de ventas");

for(i=0;i<cont;i++)
    printf("%d %.2f\n", i+1, ventasXproductos[i]);
/* ... */
```

Your `lectura` flag will not protect you from operating on incomplete data if this is selected. Enclose the code with curly braces:

```
case 4:
    if(lectura == false) {
        printf("Primero ingresa los datos del producto!!!\n");
    } else {
        printf("%35s\n", "Total de ventas");

        for(i=0;i<cont;i++)
            printf("%d %.2f\n", i+1, ventasXproductos[i]);

        /* ... */
    }

    break;
```

---

Note that in `&*seleccion`, `&` and `*` balance each other out. This resolves to the same value as just writing `seleccion` would.

---

Note that `fflush(stdin);` is also (technically) [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior), and [should not be relied upon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209/2505965).